# Таймер обратного отсчета в секундах с заданными параметрами

Tags: javascript, дата, setinterval

Здравствуйте.

Не пинайте меня, за такой длинный вопрос. По короче не получается сформулировать свои мысли.

Пытаюсь реализовать таймер обратного отсчета в секундах, так чтоб можно было задать определенную цифру или число. И от нее уже идти к 0.

У меня на странице будет несколько таймеров, которые будут содержать разные цифры старта отсчета. Если только использовать `setInterval(function(){}, 1000)`, то происходит один странный момент. У первого таймера, отсчет времени происходит по секундам, а у последующих таймеров, данный процесс происходит значительно быстрее. Выглядит это не красиво и не правильно.

Поэтому я написал, вот такую простую функцию. Но не могу ее завершить. Отсчет времени происходит от реального времени. Как реализовать подобное, но чтоб отсчет был от конкретной цифры или числа, я пока понятия не имею.

Вот мои наработки:

```
<script>
    function times(numb)
    {
        var n = new Date().getSeconds();
        var _ = (60 - n) - 1;
        return (_ < 10) ? '0' + _ : _;
    }

    window.onload = function()
    {
        var span = document.getElementById('times');

        window.setInterval(function()
        {
            span.innerHTML = times(37);
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>

<span id="times"></span>
```

Как в функции `times(numb)`, соединить реализованное с задуманным, я пока не знаю. Что необходимо дописать, чтоб заработала по данному механизму?

Comment: Там с этими таймерами много всяких нюансов. К примеру интервал очищать надо через `clearInterval` и т.д. А проще не париться и взять готовый. типа [такого](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) или [такого](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понял Вашу задумку:

```js
var numb_1 = 5;
var numb_2 = 10;
var numb_3 = 12;

function times(numb, int_id) {
  var _ = numb;
  if (_ <= 0) {
    clearInterval(int_id);
  }
  return (_ < 10) ? '0' + _ : _;
}

function interval(int_id, numb) {
  var span = document.getElementById(int_id);
  int_id = setInterval(function() {
    span.innerHTML = times(numb--, int_id);
  }, 1000);

}

interval('times1', numb_1);
interval('times2', numb_2);
interval('times3', numb_3);
```

```html
<span id="times1"></span>
<span id="times2"></span>
<span id="times3"></span>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Сам бы не догадался.